# CloudFoundry Grails - Unable to detect java compiler, make sure you're using a JDK not a JRE

Tags: java, grails, groovy, cloud-foundry

I have some really weird problem, when I deploy my grails app to CloudFOundry (run.pivotal.io), I get strange exceptions.

```
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:370)
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:51)
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] ERROR impl.DefaultContext - Unhandled exception
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT ... 7 more
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to detect java compiler, make sure you're using a JDK not a JRE!
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:108)
2015-02-16T11:12:18.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$21.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1740)
2015-02-16T11:12:06.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT Configuring Spring Security Core ...
2015-02-16T11:12:00.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT [CONTAINER] udAutoReconfigurationApplicationContextInitializer INFO Adding cloud service auto-reconfiguration to ApplicationContext
2015-02-16T11:11:58.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester INFO TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
2015-02-16T11:11:58.000+00:00 [App/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester INFO TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
```

What is that?
in BootStrap.groovy I have defined -

```
def init = { servletContext ->
vertxPlatformManager = PlatformLocator.factory.createPlatformManager()
URL[] classpath = [new File("src/java/pizzaVerticles/src/vertx/java/hello").toURI().toURL()]
vertxPlatformManager.deployVerticle("RateFetcherVerticleFirebase.java", null, classpath, 1, null, null)
vertxPlatformManager.deployVerticle("Server.java", null, classpath, 1, null, null)
vertxPlatformManager.deployVerticle("SocialTweety.java", null, classpath, 1, null, null)
}
```

there are some other bunch of things but they are records for database, which works.

First of all I had problems where I got error like Resource not found: Server.java

Error was for all three java files. Then I placed those java files inside web-app folder and when creating war it would pick them up too. But now I have this strange exception. Googled around and couldnt find anything related. I would really appreciate your help, thanks!

I am very new to CloudFoundry. App is running on grails, vertx and is built and deployed to CF using gradle. It works fine when run locally.

Comment: Well ... are you running CloudFoundry using a JDK or a JRE?

Comment: Are you uploading a war file or your java source files?

Comment: I am uploading war file created with gradle war command, which is basically grails war command. And I am using this buildpack when uploading to cloudfoundry https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#v2.4 so **@Stephen C** I am not sure if I am using JDK or JRE?

Comment: Usually when you get this error it means you are uploaded .java source files and not compiled class files.  Cloud Foundry ideally likes a compiled war with .class files instead of .java source files.  Could you try compiling your java code into .class files and then build a war?

Comment: **@JeffSloyer** I can see those .java file classes inside my war file already. But from BootStrap.groovy looks like vertxPlatformManager.deployVerticle("Server.java", null, classpath, 1, null, null) somehow wants to run exactly .java file

Comment: @pizza-app you mentioned you can see the .java files, do you mean you see .java files in your war or do you see .class files?

Comment: **@JeffSloyer** Well, yea, that sounded weird, sorry. I meant I see .class files already in war. Now I have added those .java files to war by hand also and I am getting this Compilation error because CF tries to compile .java files I guess? I was given this app to deploy it on CloudFoundry and didnt develop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running through this tutorial (http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/gsg-grails.html) to see if that works first and then try to isolate where yours isn't working.

Comment: Thing is, I am able to run the app on CF and I am able to browse it. But there are features like btc rate refreshing and tweet getting from twitter. They are run with vertx. Therefore those features are not running on app.

Comment: Oh, so it looks like an issue with vertx then...  In the above comment you had `vertxPlatformManager.deployVerticle("Server.java", null, classpath, 1, null, null)`.  That won't work the best in CF since its looking for a .java file.  Ideally you will need to get compiled jar's or class files...

Comment: **@JeffSloyer** So you suggest to somehow remake that commandline so it uses not .java files but .jar or .class files? Will CF be able to compile them that way?

Comment: Yeah ideally use jar files or compiled class files if you could

Comment: Ok, thanks, will look in to it. Picked as correct answer for now :)